# Manga where the Mc kills the demon lord but finds the demon lord's daughter in the next room and raises her

Tags: story-identification, manga

The Mc/hero kills the demon lord but hears a noise from the other room and turns out to be the demon lord's daughter so he puts on armor and pretends to be a demon general or something like that and decides to raise the demon lord's daughter

Comment: If anyone correctly identifies the manga you're looking for, please mark that answer as [accepted](https://scifi.stackexchange.com/help/accepted-answer) by clicking on the check mark beneath the voting buttons. Thanks.

Answer (score 3):

I believe its "Uchi no Maou ga Tenshi de tsurai" where the story roughly is: the MC/Hero slained the Demon Lord (before the Demon Lord died, she asked the hero to take care of her daughter, which the MC later willing to do it just to fulfill a mother's death wish), in which he wears the dark knight armor to conceal his identity and take care of the Demon Lord daughter[image]

Comment: Welcome to SFF! Could you [edit] this to explain how it matches the description given in the question? I.e. why do you think this is the correct manga?

Comment: Sorry for the confusion, but we're asking for actual details like "In chapter 2, Bob shows up alongside Miu, and he explains that she's the daughter of the Demon Lord he defeated in chapter 1", or a quoted description of the series with a link to the place where you got the description (note, please don't link to any pirate sites). Screenshots from the manga can be even better because the querent can see the art style, which is hard to describe in words.

Comment: Am I allowed to put a brief summary where it might contain mild spoilers? Also i know pirated sites are illegal but what abt screenshots from there?

Comment: @Andrew Loh Yes, spoilers are fine when it pertains to something in the original question, since presumably the OP has already read it. In many cases it's enough to grab a synopsis from a database-type site (e.g. mangaupdates.com), but for this title some plot details are needed. Screenshots should be fine as long as they're not overused, as that should fall under fair-use.

Answer (score 1):

Maybe your talking about [Aesthetica of a Rogue Hero](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Aesthetica_of_a_Rogue_Hero)

"The story follows a world where several young men and women regularly find themselves spirited away to a world of sword and magic called Alayzard (アレイザード, Areizādo). Those who survive and return are typically gifted with magic abilities. An international training organization named Babel protects these young returnees and trains them in the use of their power. **A wayward hero named Akatsuki has come back to his world, along with a beautiful girl called Miu who is the daughter of the Last Dark Lord, whom he defeated in battle.**"

Also i thought about [Kuro no Shoukanshi](https://kuro-no-shoukanshi.fandom.com/wiki/Kuro_no_Shoukanshi_Wiki) or "Black Summoner" :
The main character doesn't kill the demon lord but his vassal who was protecting the demon lord's daughter and then takes care of her.